# Is there any special formula for this part of logarithma?

Tags: limits, analysis

> **Exercise 2.** Compute the following limit$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{2\arctan(x)\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{x^3-2x^4}{\ln(2x+2x^2)}-\ln(1+2x+2x^2)}{e^{x-\frac{x^2}2}-\cos(x^2)+\tan(2x^4-x)+x^2e^{-\frac1{x}}}$$

My question is that is there any special formula for this part of question? As you can see, question has a lot of parts that are needed to be solved seperately . I used $(x-x^3/3+x^5/5-...)$ for $\arctan(x)$, and $e^x=1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...$ and else. But I couldn't find any formula for this section

Comment: Is this spam? ${}$

Comment: @EF This question looks quite complicated. Can you please share where this question is from?

Comment: This is one of my previous mathematical analysis 1 exam questions at university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle term in the numerator goes to zero more quickly than $x^3$ because of the division by $\ln x$.  It turns out the numerator and denominator are of order $x^3$ so you can ignore it and work on the rest.  There is the standard series of $\ln (1+x) \approx x-\frac {x^2}2+\frac {x^3}3-\ldots$

I put the numerator into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%202arctan(x)*sqrt(1-x%5E2)-log(1%2B2x%2B2x%5E2)%20near%200) and it is about $-\frac {x^3}3$.  The [denominator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20exp(x-x%5E2%2F2)-cos(x%5E2)%2Btan(2x%5E4-x)%2Bx%5E2exp(-1%2Fx%5E2)%20near%200) is about $-\frac {2x^3}3$ so the limit is $\frac 12$

Comment: If we remove the middle term from numerator then the remaining terms should be like $2x+\dots - 2x+\dots$ so that there should not be any term with $x$ left. I am also surprised how alpha gives $4x$.

Comment: You have input $\ln(1-2x-2x^2)$ instead of $\ln(1+2x+2x^2)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh:  You are right.  I fixed that and got a finite limit.  I am still surprised that it only took terms out to $x^3$.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the log term in middle of numerator is $o(x^3)$ but not $o(x^{3+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon >0$ and can only be ignored only if the denominator has some non-zero coefficients upto $x^3$. And we are lucky that it is so.

Comment: I suppose a typo at the very end : $\frac 12$ seems to be better. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  Yes, I found one minus sign but not the other.